# Cant open style.css.map through scss comiling

Tags: javascript, css, sass, package.json

When i tried to open style.css.map i got this error i don't know why. I tried removing the image from the CSS, it did not help.

There is the way how do i add css and css.map in package-json: "style": "sass --watch src/sass/style.scss src/sass/style.css", css is working but css.map throw the mistake.

The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: MustSpecifyImageSize" @ error/map.c/ReadMAPImage/148

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do anything with any .map file, its a temporary file thats used to compile one thing into another.. its a byproduct of a css to scss conversion.

Id recommend setting up something like webpack or using your IDE to compile the scss

Comment: that`s a problem. I build webpack like this and still have the problem: 

const devMode = mode === 'development'
/const devtool = devMode ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : undefined

module.exports = {
    devtool
}